# Start Node JS application when server reboots with pm2

Tags: node.js, ubuntu-14.04, pm2

I am trying to use the module `pm2` to start my node js app everytime the server boots.
I have used the command `pm2 startup ubuntu` but each time I restart the server, my application is not running and I have to start it manually again.

Any ideas what is causing this issue?

Comment: put some of your code here please, its quite impossible to suggest a solution otherwise.

Comment: @sam100rav what difference would his code make? this is a question of starting a node app automatically on reboot.

Comment: what does `pm2 logs` say?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Make sure you do save your processes:

```
pm2 start app.js 
pm2 startup ubuntu 
pm2 save
```

> Once you have started the apps and want to keep them on server reboot
>   do: `pm2 save`

Source: https://github.com/Unitech/PM2/blob/master/ADVANCED_README.md#startup-script

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32839213/pm2-startup-doesnt-work/34820339#34820339

Answer (score 0):

Go to your server directory and use the following commands:

```
pm2 start <your_app_name.js>
pm2 startup ubuntu
pm2 save
```