# node startup script NOT working

Tags: node.js, startup, pm2

I have a node app that I would like to run at startup but I cannot get it to work. I am running Ubuntu 14.04. The first command starts the process and works as intended but when I run `pm2 startup` and `pm2 save` from below and reboot the box I have no luck with the app launching at boot.

```
# Start the process
NODE_ENV="production" pm2 start /home/expressjs/app_name/app.js -u expressjs --watch --name "app_name"
# Create a startup script and save the process.
sudo env PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/bin pm2 startup ubuntu -u expressjs
pm2 save
```

Comment: Dupe (but without an accepted answer): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32053549/start-node-js-application-when-server-reboots-with-pm2

Comment: Yeah this is not a dupe. Did you read my question? The solution that you reference is what I have posted above but it's clearly not working which is why I posted a question here.

Comment: I didn't actually vote to close it as a dupe. i simply listed another VERY similar question. At the time it had no answer. No harm intended.