# Ubuntu 14.04 - pm2 startup not starting after reboot

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-14.04, pm2

I am using pm2 to start a node.js process, and I would like this process to be started automatically when the system (Ubuntu 14.04 on Intel Atom processor) is booted. I have followed the instructions on the [pm2 web site](http://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/startup/#startup-systems-support) but without success. My dump.pm2 appears to be correct, but the pm2 daemon is never started. I have tried both the `ubuntu` and `linux` options to `pm2 startup`, as well as autodetect, both with and without a specified user. Files (links) `S20pm2-init.sh` have been created in `/etc/rc[2-5].d` but nothing gets started. I can't find find any obvious error messages in the system log.

Any ideas?

**Edit to add**

I find that
    `service pm2-init.sh start` starts the daemon correctly, when run from my login account, which is the same as that defined by `USER=` in the file `/etc/init.d/pm2-init.sh`. I've made sure the `PM2_HOME` definition in this file points to the correct place as well. However, it still doesn't start on system boot!

Comment: I'm using pm2 on Ubuntu 15.04, I tried all the possible solutions start the save but nothing when rebooting my server, please advice?

Answer (score 8):

For pm2 startup to work, there's a critical command buried in [documentation](http://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/startup/#saving-current-processes) and [here.](https://github.com/Unitech/pm2#startup-script-generation)

> You have to 1) start all your processes, 2) create the startup script, and 3) run `pm2 save`

Reference to [@lazlojuly's answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32056700/3998770).

Comment: This works great for me - without any custom hack or customization to startup script in my Digital Ocean Ubuntu droplet.

Comment: +1 Crazy this is not included in their [startup documentation](http://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/quick-start/)

Answer (score 7):

What steps work for me on Ubuntu `18.04.4`

1. `npm i pm2 -g`
2. run this command as root user: `pm2 startup`

   - creates service `pm2-root` found in `/etc/systemd/system`
3. `systemctl enable pm2-root`, `service pm2-root status`

   - **Note**: after Node upgrade, run these commands as root: `pm2 unstartup`, `pm2 startup`; [documentation](https://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/startup/#generating-a-startup-script)
4. `pm2 start dist\index.js --name YourNodeApp`
5. `pm2 save`
6. `reboot`
7. `pm2 ls` should show your `YourNodeApp` online

Answer (score 3):

Well, I think this worked, anyway. I was originally trying to start as a system user (no login shell) called `node-red` running the node application of the same name, and when that didn't work I tried starting as ordinary user `max`. After some fiddling with things it suddenly started working, **but** on this slow Atom processor, the node application starts only a couple of minutes after the desktop appears.

To get it running under the system user: first, logged in as `max`, I deleted all pm2 jobs and ran `pm2 save` to create a empty dump file. Then I did:

```
sudo npm install pm2@latest -g
pm2 update
```

To get the latest version, in case that helped. I moved from 0.14.7 to 0.15.7

Then I ran

```
sudo su -c "env PATH=$PATH:/usr/bin pm2 startup ubuntu -u node-red"
```

and edited `/etc/init.d/pm2-init.sh` correcting the line that sets the `PM2_HOME` directory to the home directory of `node-red`:

```
export PM2_HOME="/home/node-red/.pm2"
```

Then I became a login version of the `node-red` user, changed to that user's home directory, started my job, and saved the process list:

```
sudo -H -u node-red bash -l
cd
pm2 start /usr/local/bin/node-red --node-args="--max-old-space-size=128" -- -v -u /home/node-red/.node-red
pm2 save
```

Then I exited from `node-red`'s shell, rebooted, and (after a minute or so's delay) there was the application running nicely!

Note that this was ubuntu 14.04, which uses the `init`/`upstart` system. Later versions I think use `systemd` approach and may need the `ubuntu` parameter changed to `systemd` when creating the startup script.

I'm still not really sure why it didn't work properly the first time, though.

Comment: this line here `export PM2_HOME="/home/node-red/.pm2"` was the fix for me. it was `export PM2_HOME="/root/.pm2"` for some reason

Answer (score 1):

Basically,

**Step 1:** Run following command,

```
pm2 startup
```

Here you will get 1 command generated, `copy/paste` it and done.

(Sample command you will get from above step: `sudo env PATH=$PATH:/usr/bin /usr/lib/node_modules/pm2/bin/pm2 startup systemd -u ubuntu --hp /home/ubuntu`)
[Ref](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37738360/3411787)

Answer (score 0):

I been searching for work around for quit while till i came to this solution

after executing pm2 save

1. this file will be created -> /etc/init.d/pm2-init.sh
2. then on cron tab
    @reboot root /etc/init.d/pm2-init.sh start
   this equivalent to executing it on cmd but triggered on reboot

this is working fine for me now